# Protect entry so that only a "relatedTo" user can see it

Tags: entry, authentication

I would like to protect the viewing of an _entry.html page so that only a user related to that entry can view it.

Answer (score 2):

You could loop through the users and compare them.

```
{% set authorized = false %}
{% for user in entry.authorizedUsers %}
    {% if user == currentUser %}
        {% set authorized = true %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if not authorized %}
    {% redirect 403 %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Ahha! I didn't know about redirect tag, will give that a shot, thanks

Comment: Glad to help. Let me know if that first option works. I'm curious myself. Also, you can redirect anywhere with the `redirect` method (I just chose 403 as an example), or display alternate content if you like. You may also have to check if there is a currentUser at all, using `{% if currentUser %}... {% endif %}`

Comment: Pretty sure Twig doesn't have an `in_array`.  It does have an `in`, so you could do `{% if not currentUser in entry.authorizedUsers %}`, but I doubt that will work when comparing whole objects to each other. Would probably need to just do the comparison on authorId, but honestly your 2nd solution seems better.

Comment: @Brad.... thanks. I was looking at a [post on the twig stack exchange](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460481/twig-in-array-or-similar-possible-within-if-statement) and misread it. As you say, still may not work.